# CLOC - how to count loc in a specific (unique) directory using match-d

Tags: lines-of-code, cloc

I need to count lines of code in a specific directory named 'gen' and I cannot just hard code the path to this directory because it can be anywhere inside a root directory (the path is variable). Would be possible to use match-d? I don't want however to include all directories that contain 'gen', therefore this will not work:

--match-d = 'gen'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `--fullpath` (to let the filter apply to the entire directory path instead of just the trailing directory name) and positive or negative look-aheads in `--match-d` to isolate the `/gen/` subdirectory of interest.

If you post a sample directory structure you're working with and identify the directories you want and don't want, I will take a shot at writing a `--match-d` expression to meet your needs.